# AWK - count the number of syllables in a word

Tags: regex, awk

I need to know if the words are monosyllabic or polysyllabic. The way I am going to apply to find out is by counting the number of blocks of vowels.

I tried with this regex, but does not work well with all the words
`number_of_vowels=match($1,"[aouöüeiáóúőűéí]?[aouöüeiáóúőűéí]");`

In

```
könyvtaár
könyvter
hozzászóles
mű
cikk
ős
```

Desired output

```
könyvtaár    2    polysyllabic
könyvter    2     polysyllabic   
hozzászóles    4    polysyllabic
mű    1    monosyllabic
cikk    1    monosyllabic
ős    1    monosyllabic
```

Now I'm using this regex

`a=match($1,"[aouöüeiáóúőűéí]+");`

And for this word "hozzászóles" it's giving me 2, not 4.

For more information, these are de consonats `"b c cs d dz dzs f g gy h j k l ly m n ny p q r s sz t ty v w x y z zs"`

Comment: how is `könyvtaár` just 2 syllabus ?

Comment: @Thomas Don't worry about it! for me is bisyllabic.

Comment: I can't help you if I don't understand your logic, sorry.

Comment: He is considering that only these are vowels: `aouöüeiáóúőűéí`. `y` is not in it. That's just it.

Comment: @antoine-sac then tell me how `öaá` is only two vowels.

Comment: @Firefly: `match` function doesn't return # of of matches. It returns **the character position (index) at which that substring begins (one, if it starts at the beginning of string). If no match is found, return zero.**

Comment: @Thomas: it is not 2 vowels, but it is one syllable (or at least one block of vowels which is what OP is interested in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an awk function to count occurrences of a regep (e.g. if it's part of a larger script) then you need to use `split()` or `gsub()`, not `match()`:

```
$ awk '{a=split($0,t,/[aouöüeiáóúőűéí]+/); print $0, a-1, (a>2?"poly":"mono")"syllabic"}' file
könyvtaár 2 polysyllabic
könyvter 2 polysyllabic
hozzászóles 4 polysyllabic
mű 1 monosyllabic
cikk 1 monosyllabic
ős 1 monosyllabic

$ awk '{t=$0; a=gsub(/[aouöüeiáóúőűéí]+/,"",t); print $0, a, (a>1?"poly":"mono")"syllabic"}' file
könyvtaár 2 polysyllabic
könyvter 2 polysyllabic
hozzászóles 4 polysyllabic
mű 1 monosyllabic
cikk 1 monosyllabic
ős 1 monosyllabic
```

but if you don't need a function to do it then just use @anubhava's approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F '[aouöüeiáóúőűéí]+' 'NF{
        print $0, NF-1, (NF>2) ? "polysyllabic" : "monosyllabic"}' file | column -t
```

**Output:**

```
könyvtaár    2  polysyllabic
könyvter     2  polysyllabic
hozzászóles  4  polysyllabic
mű           1  monosyllabic
cikk         1  monosyllabic
ős           1  monosyllabic
```

Comment: Yes I know but there are 3 vowels in that and you commented it as well.

Comment: It seems that *"Two vowels together count only as one"*. That shouldn't be too difficult to fix.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, Yes just a quantifier takes care of that.